# complete documentation for ActiveRecord::Base, including list of instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to get a list of all available public methods for subclasses of ActiveRecord::Base (i.e., rails model classes).  After searching for an existing answer to this question, I'm surprised that I found nothing.  I tried "ri ActiveRecord::Base", which has some good documentation on the capabilities of model classes and how they work, but no list of instance-, or class-, methods; and, of course, I tried googling, and had no luck.  I know that I can run a piece of rails code that can provide such a list (using, I think, MyModelClass.instance_methods), but that's much less convenient than simply using ri on the command line, or even finding this list in documentation online (if it existed, and it apparently doesn't).

Is such a list available anywhere (other than by extracting it manually from the source code)?  From looking so far, it seems to me that it is not.  (I guess there's an implied request here for more complete Rails documentation, but that topic is, of course, not relevant to stackoverflow.)

(edit:) I probably should have mentioned that
I'm aware of the auto-generated methods and that a lot of the methods available on ActiveRecord models come from modules included by ActiveRecord::Base.  (I wanted to keep the question from getting too long, but leaving this out was probably unwise.)  I suppose one of my points is that since ActiveRecord::Base presents an interface, the method names that are part of that interface (IMO, of course), including the ones from included modules should be included in the documentation of ActiveRecord::Base.  (Doesn't 'ri Array', for example, list methods that come from Enumerable - such as collect and select?)  My view is that tedious work such as looking up docs for included modules should be done by our computers and software rather than by us (so that we can spend time on more important work, like developing software).  Anyway, the main point of my question was whether this info (AR model methods such as 'touch', 'becomes', 'increment', ...) was available in one convenient place.  It seems the answer is no.

Thanks for the responses, though.  I ended up putting together a simple, naive script that might be of some use - it simply uses ri to get the list of included modules and then runs ri on the main class and on those modules.  (I suppose I should also include the extended modules.)  Here's the script, in case anyone might find it helpful:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run 'ri' on $1 and all modules included by class $1

class=$1
if [ -z "$class" ]; then exit 0; fi

set $(ri $class|col -b|awk '/Includes:/{go=1} (go && $0 ~ /^  *[A-Z]/) {print} (go && $0 ~ /^ *$/) {exit}')

ri $class|col -b
base=$(echo $class|sed 's@::[^:]*$@@')
for m; do
    ri $base::$m|col -b
done
```

Comment: The problem is that the majority if your instance methods depends on your DB structure, since the ORM will be mapping them against the structure for columns etc. For all other methods, you'll need to look at the Included Modules defined here: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: The reason you don't see individually documented methods for `ActiveRecord::Base` is because that class does not actually define its own methods. All the methods available in `ActiveRecord::Base` are populated by including (32) and extending (13) modules [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L277) These modules may also include and/or extend modules as well. If you are interested in a certain method find out what module that method belongs too and review the documentation there.

Comment: Also please remember that some of the methods are generated dynamically at run time and do not technically exist in the source code other than in a meta capacity.